# Shift image. OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, opencv

I use the following code to shift the image:

```
    Mat img = Cv2.ImRead(@"C:\building.jpg", ImreadModes.GrayScale);        
    Mat imgout = new Mat();

    Point2f[] src = new Point2f[3];
    src[1] = new Point2f(0, 0);
    src[1] = new Point2f(img.Width-1, 0);
    src[2] = new Point2f(0, img.Height-1);

    Point2f[] dst = new Point2f[3];
    dst[0] = new Point2f(-100, 0);
    dst[1] = new Point2f((img.Width - 1)-100, 0);
    dst[2] = new Point2f(-100, img.Height - 1);


    var m = Cv2.GetAffineTransform(src, dst);
    Cv2.WarpAffine(img, imgout, m, img.Size());
```

I know that you can make it easier. How?

Answer (score 1):

Affine Transform is rather complicated operation. Simple shift can be done by copy of submatrix (roi) to the new matrix of the same size as original.

Shift Width and Height can be set as parameters of a function. All operations can be done in three lines (read image, create new mat, copy of submat to new mat), but defining rois as separate operations makes code clearer.

```
int shiftWidth = -100;
int shiftHeight = -100;
Mat img = Cv2.ImRead(@"C:\building.jpg", ImreadModes.GrayScale);
Mat imgout = new Mat(img.Size(), img.Type());
OpenCvSharp.Rect sourceRoi = new OpenCvSharp.Rect(Math.Max(-shiftWidth, 0), Math.Max(-shiftHeight, 0), img.Width - Math.Abs(shiftWidth), img.Height - Math.Abs(shiftHeight));
OpenCvSharp.Rect destRoi = new OpenCvSharp.Rect(Math.Max(shiftWidth, 0), Math.Max(shiftHeight, 0), img.Width - Math.Abs(shiftWidth), img.Height - Math.Abs(shiftHeight));
img.SubMat(sourceRoi).CopyTo(imgout.SubMat(destRoi));
```

Comment: I would be appreciated, if you accept the answer if it helped you.